# Gallerific SlideShow Thumb Pics Vertical Appearance

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented the Gallerific SlideShow, and the issue that Im having is that the Thumb Pics appear vertically in a column of 2.

http://www.davincispainting.com/InteriorGallery.aspx

I need these Thumbs to appear horizontally across with 10 Pics X 2 Columns

I have tried to determine where to change this in the galleriffic.js however to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean horizontally across with 2 rows? From the Gallerrific page:

> **How can I change the number of
>   thumbnail columns?**
>
> With the stylesheet used in these
>   examples, each thumbnail is floated
>   left, and thus as many thumbnails that
>   will fit in the width of the column
>   will be displayed. If you want fewer
>   or more columns, make the width of the
>   navigation panel smaller or larger. In
>   all but the last example, I am setting
>   the width using javascript with the
>   following lines in the html page:
>
> ```
> $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '300px', 'float' : 'left'});
> $('div.content').css('display', 'block');
> ```

In your HTML, find the line:

```
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation" style="width: 300px; float: left; opacity: 1; ">
```

and increase that width. You may have to play with the exact number.